# Yamllint Indentation Warning on Valid Ansible code

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following task in my playbooks:

```
    - name: gather os specific variables
      include_vars: "{{ item }}"
      with_first_found:
        - files:
          - "{{ ansible_distro }}-{{
                ansible_distribution_version|lower|replace('/', '_') }}.yml"
          - "{{ ansible_distro }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
          - "{{ ansible_distro }}-{{
                ansible_distribution_major_version|lower|replace('/', '_') }}.yml"
          - "{{ ansible_distro }}.yml"
          - "{{ ansible_os_family|lower }}.yml"
          paths:
          - ../vars
          skip: true
```

This is correct as of https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/first_found.py.

Yamllint is giving me the following error:

```
  10:7      warning  wrong indentation: expected 8 but found 6  (indentation)
  18:7      warning  wrong indentation: expected 8 but found 6  (indentation)
```

Why is Yamllint complaining here and how can I correct it so that it conforms while still being a valid Ansible task?

Answer (score 1):

Correct for parsing, but not good enough for linter to pass.

Add two spaces for nicer look:

```
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distro }}-{{
      ^^ here
```

and here:

```
      paths:
        - ../vars
      ^^
```

Comment: We've actually converted away from that- removing those two extra spaces. With python's yamllint [the config is](http://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules.html#module-yamllint.rules.indentation) `indent-sequences: false`